# Access Internal Storage without internal SD-Card

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, data-recovery, data-transfer, internal-sd

In Marshmallow you can format SD-Cards as internal. Android then merges the Internal Storage and the SD-Card Storage. If the SD-Card is removed, the internal storage can’t be accessed without inserting the Card again.

My SD-Card is corrupted (so android says) and can’t be mounted. Windows is able to access the Card which is mostly empty. Some standard files Android created are on there, the data is gone. Deleted Data on the SD-Card has been partially restored with appropriate Programs.

This leaves me without a possibility to access the files on the Internal Storage. However the files still seem to be there. When I accidently re-downloaded a file, chrome asked me to override that file. Either chrome can still access the files in the download folder (however downloading new files does not work, so it might be read only). Or chrome keeps a separate list, detecting duplicates before it accesses the storage.

Things that don’t work:
- Using a file Manager to access /data or /storage/self (Solid explorer sends an “Access denied” error)
- Connecting the Phone to a PC via MTP (Does not display any storage)
- Using an Android data recovery Program (Wondershare) does not display any relevant Files.
- Repairing the SD-Card using Windows, as Windows does not detect any Errors
- Using ADB pull (0 files pulled for /data, special files skipped for /storage/self)
- Using ADB shell (“Access denied” as expected)

Things that might work:
- Telling Android the SD-Card is not coming back (“Remove internal SD-Card”):
I can’t find any information on how Android is going to handle this. Maybe this will result in reformatting the internal data partition. The dialog states that data on the Card will be lost, however it doesn’t talk about internal Data. In case of data loss it might be a good idea to have a good recovery program installed as installing it afterwards might override Data. Kind of the last resort.
- Trying to root the Phone without wiping the data partition (tethered root). I’m not sure I will have access to the folders. Wondershare uses tethered root and does not display any pictures ect.
- Repairing the SD using Linux. However I don’t have a suitable machine at hand.
- Physically soldering to access the storage (I’m not doing that)

Maybe some of you could shed some light on the way the data is stored/ access is blocked / root affects this block or faced similar problems already. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Device: Moto g 2015 running 6.0.1

Comment: Info online is that an [adopted card](https://fossbytes.com/android-sd-card-internal-storage-adoptable-storage/) is encrypted and can't be mounted elsewhere. That the SD card could be mounted under Windows suggests that it no longer has the encrypted data, which is probably why Android states it's corrupted.